# Readless Preflop Strategy for Pokerstars HU Hyperturbo SNGs?

Tags: nlhe, heads-up, pre-flop, range

I ran into several materials about hyperturbo heads-up SNGs from different sources, and their preflop ranges readless are really different.

Some reccomend open raising 90-100% hands, others limping with some hands or going preflop all in with weak Ax and 22-99.

For playing out of BB, situation is similar. Some recommend calling or 3betting pairs, broadways and SC, others add hands like {98o, K5o, J3s} to BB calling/3betting range.
Question is relative to early phase stakes 1$-10$ without reads.(20-25bb Effective stack.)

What range do u use and why?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Is the 20-25bb stack what you start with? Also, is it 6max or Full Ring? How quick do the blinds increase and by how much each level? Thanks. I'd assume some use of Nash's equilibriums might come into this.

Comment: HT HU SNG == hyperturbo heads up(2 players) starts at 25bb. How fast or how much blind increase is irrelevant to strategy. Using NASH deeper then 7BB is wasting of equity, although you can apply it vs good opponents up to 12bb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely depends on your opponent.

You can start out min-raising 90-100% but if he 3-bet shoves a ton then you can't do this. Or you can try limping and min-betting lots of flops, but he if shoves PF from the BB a ton, you can't do it (there is a hint as to how you should play against people who take those strategies themselves!).

Against really good opponents you wont be able to just have a boiler plate strategy and stick to it because they'll quickly adjust to it and exploit you. You have to keep adjusting and they will keep adjusting - the winner is the person who adjusts faster, or the one who ends up having a hand or getting lucky when there is a called all-in.

Don't undervalue post-flop play though. It might not seem that important with so few BB's, but it is! Getting in some good value bets/bluffs/semi-bluffs or knowing when to fold post-flop can give you the edge against an opponent who plays bad post-flop but whom you are evenly matched against pre-flop.

Knowing all of that, if you still want a cheat-sheet, something like this:

-Min-raise top 75% of hands from SB, C-bet 100% of flops

```
AA-22, AKs-A2s, KQs-K2s, QJs-Q2s, JTs-J2s, 
T9s-T2s, 98s-92s, 87s-83s, 76s-73s, 65s-63s, 
54s-52s, 43s, AKo-A2o, KQo-K2o, QJo-Q2o, 
JTo-J4o, T9o-T6o, 98o-96o, 87o-86o, 76o-75o, 65o
```

-3-bet all-in with top 50% of hands from BB

```
AA-33, AKs-A2s, KQs-K2s, QJs-Q2s, JTs-J4s, 
T9s-T6s, 98s-96s, 87s-86s, 76s, 65s, AKo-A2o, 
KQo-K5o, QJo-Q7o, JTo-J7o, T9o-T7o, 98o
```

Fold/check everything else, and play TAG post-flop. Consider trapping with the top of your range sometimes instead of raising or shoving (i.e. limp or call w/ AA/KK).

If you are playing a super aggressive opponent, flip those ranges. Min-raise top 50% and 3-bet shove top 75% - and trap every time you have a top 10% hand:

```
AA-77, AKs-A9s, KQs-KTs, QJs-QTs, AKo-AJo, KQo
```

Then check-raise most flops when you bricked or have a medium strength hand. If you have a strong hand, either slow-play it or bet into him on the flop or turn and hope he spazzes out and raises you.

I repeat: A good opponent is going to pick up on your strategy quickly and exploit you if you just follow the cheat sheet blindly, particularly if you play multiple games together. To win with a strategy like this, you must be able to make adjustments based on how your opponent plays and how you think your opponent thinks you play and how you think your opponent thinks you think he plays etc. etc. etc.

Ranges from: http://pokerstove.com/site/analysis/allin-discuss.php